# Tenho um retorno em Json e quero pegar os dados em C# (Dados de CNPJ)

Tags: c#, json

Tenho um link que eu passo o CNPJ (https://www.receitaws.com.br/v1/cnpj/@cnpj) e ele me retorna um json com todas as informações, qual é a minha duvida, como faço para pegar essas informações como Razão social, Nome Fantazia, Endereço e Inseri-las no textBox da Aplicação? Ja tentei algumas coisas e sinceramente não sai do lugar, podem me ajudar?

Fiz um exemplo que foi passado em um site, ate consigo capturar todo o resultado, porem não consigo pegar os dados dentro desse resultado:

var client = new WebClient();
var conteudo = client.DownloadString("https://www.receitaws.com.br/v1/cnpj/@cnpj".Replace("@cnpj", txtCNPJ.Text));

Obrigado.

Comment: Poste seu código para podermos ajuda-lo

Comment: XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
var client = new WebClient();

var conteudo = client.DownloadString("https://www.receitaws.com.br/v1/cnpj/@cnpj".Replace("@cnpj", txtCNPJ.Text));

string json = conteudo;

XNode node = JsonConvert.DeserializeXNode(json, "Root"); 

string xml = node.ToString();ds.ReadXml(xml);

string verificar = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Resultado"].ToString(); 

if (verificar == "1")
{ 
txtEndereco.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["logradouro"].ToString(); 
}
Desa maneira esta dando estouro de URI, pois esta como XML, precisa ser Json

Comment: Só para entender você consegue obter os dados no formato xml certo, e quer converte-lo para json é isso ?

Comment: Vamos la, eu obtenho os dados Json já porem não sei como pegar o resultado e jogar dentro dos TextBox do sistema, no caso pegar o "Endereço" do json e jogar no textbox Endereco do sistema entende? tipo separar os dados para colocar em seus lugares na tela

Answer (score 0):

Tente deserializar o objeto json que você recebe o JsonConvert.DeserializeObject da namespace NewtonSoft.Json. [Link NewtonSoft](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json).

Você basicamente vai obter seu json e convertelo para uma classe ou object do c#, e utiliza-lo normalmente no seu programa.

```
//Passando um tipo de referencia
//conteudo é seu json
var meuObjConvertido = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SuaClasse>(conteudo);

//ou
var meuObjConvertido = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(conteudo); //Retorna um object
```